# How to keep variables in memory outside of debugging mode in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am writing python code and switched from spyder to VSCode and I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the variables in the memory outside of the debugging mode.

I want to keep the variables to look inside and/or to run just single lines/sections again without running the whole script.

Comment: I do not understand what you want, Use Jupyter notebook or a REPL interface

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a Jupyter notebook style form of programming.

There is a guide on how to use Jupyter notebooks in VS Code [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks).

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements**

VS Code Extensions:

- Python (Microsoft)
- Jupyter (Microsoft)

**Shortcut (Windows)**

Shift + Enter